# Warning while compiling a c code - Dont know the reason

Tags: c

I have the following c source. But I get a warning as mentioned below

```
void check_func();
int var2[16][128];
int var1[][128];
int i, k;

int main()
{
    for (i = 0u; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0u; k < 128; k++)
        {
            var2[i][k] = 4095;
        }
    }

    check_func();

    //printf("%d", var1[0]);
    return 1;
}

void check_func()
{
    var1 = &var2[0][0];
    return;
}
```

I get a warning when compiled in gcc.

E:\gcc-2.95.2\bin>gcc.exe check.c
check.c: In function `check_func':
check.c:24:`var1' has an incomplete type
check.c: At top level:
check.c:3: warning: array `var1' assumed to have one element

**What is the reason for this warning and how to get rid of this?**
I tried type casting it to both (int (*)[]) and (void *) but still the warning persits.

i.e.

1st try:

```
var1 = (int (*)[])&var2[0][0];
```

2nd try:

```
var1 = (void *)&var2[0][0];
```

Comment: Hint: look at `int var1[][128];`

Comment: Assuming `var1` *would* be of complete type, you still could not assign to an array, but only to its elements.

Comment: Is that not array of pointers?

Comment: No.  Read up at http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html.  If you want an array of pointers, it would need to be `int* var1[128]`. (But based on what you're trying to do in `check_func`, you actually want `var1` to be just an `int*`.)

Answer (score 2):

First, let's ignore the 2D array aspect.  It's not quite relevant to a fundamental misunderstanding that you have about arrays and pointers, and it adds extra complication.

With `var1`, you're basically attempting to declare a global variable:

```
int x[];
```

which isn't legal.  Based on your comments, you seem to be under the mistaken impression that this declares a pointer, but it instead declares an array of unspecified size.  As a global variable, the compiler must be able to allocate memory for this array, but that isn't possible without knowing its size.

Note that this would be different if such a declaration were used for a function parameter:

```
void foo(int x[]);
```

[*When used as function parameters*, `int x[]` and `int* x` are interchangeable.](http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) The function does not allocate any space for the array; the array must have been allocated already, and the function instead takes a pointer to that array (or more precisely, to the array's first element).

Pointers and arrays are not the same thing.  Arrays *decay* into pointers in *certain contexts*, and function parameters allow using either syntax, but they are otherwise distinct.

---

Based on what you're trying to do in `check_func`:

```
var1 = &var2[0][0];
```

you probably want to declare `var1` simply as:

```
int* var1;
```

1. `var2` is a 2D array of `int`.
2. Therefore `var2[0][0]` is of type `int`.
3. Therefore `&var2[0][0]` is of type `int*`.
4. Therefore `var1` should be of type `int*` to match.

Comment: I will try... thanks... Actually I am testing var1 (this code is a sample code I wrote to check how var1 can be initialised), so I think I should change the way I declare var2. Probably array of pointers *var2[128] or something like that?

Comment: @giboo It depends on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish.